# How to turn off email you receive when registered?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, user-registration

My client wants to turn off the email you receive when register.

Comment: If you disable registration notifications for users, how will they activate accounts? How will they get the password?

Comment: Yeah it's weird the client wants to send it manually but I've manage to find a way with a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that generates the new user notification is `wp_new_user_notification()`.  It is called by another (similarly named) function `wp_new_user_notifications()` which is triggered by the action hook `register_new_user` in the `register_new_user()` function.

If you follow that (or even if you don't), all you need to do is remove the `wp_new_user_notifications()` filter from the `register_new_user` action:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
});
```

As others have noted, if you remove this, then depending on how you have the site set up with user passwords, etc, you may have to consider how users will be able to initially access the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a new replacement [wp_new_user_notification](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) that does not send notifications in a plugin. It's a [pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), meaning that the WordPress core version is only used if a plugin hasn't defined a version already.

You'll find the current core version in [wp-includes/pluggable.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.1.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1874). If you still want the admin notification email then copy everything up to `$key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );` into your replacement.

Beware that this is now a fairly poor experience for new users: they'll have to sign up and then use your login form to reset their password. Unless you have some other mechanism for setting and sending them credentials.