# Wordpress is sending an empty email after using wp_insert_user

Tags: user-registration

I have some issues with this method:

```
    funtion AddUser($data){
    $WP_array = array(
        'user_login'            =>  "info here",
        'user_email'            =>  "info here",
        'user_pass'             =>  "info here",
        'first_name'            =>  "info here",
        'last_name'             =>  "info here",
        'role'                  =>  "info here",
        'show_admin_bar_front'  =>  "info here",
    ) ;
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($WP_array);
}
```

After adding the new user,wordpress automatically sends an empty email D: so what can I do to prevent that, I actually used on my functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
});
```

Do you have any clue ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The empty email goes to the user or admin?

Comment: it goes to the user :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs to live inside a plugin and not in functions.php
[How to turn off email you receive when registered?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333820/how-to-turn-off-email-you-receive-when-registered)